# What is the latest stable Rails version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the latest stable version of rails? I want to install rails 3.1 but I see there is 3.1.3 now,  what is the difference? What ruby version is it most compatible with?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I recommend to always **check on GitHub via the "branches" menu what the latest version is on each branch**.
You can see the latest version easily by checking the contents of the `RAILS_VERSION` file

https://github.com/rails/rails

You could also check RubyOnRails.org, but looking at the source code is the most reliable way.

If you already have a Rails App in production, I would highly recommend: **don't just blindly take the latest version** just because it just came out -- there were many cases in the past where a new version introduced incompatibilities or new bugs which were serious enough to have to wait for a fix before the features in the Rails release were really usable. I know a couple of people who have Production sites and still run 3.0.11 or lower, rather than 3.l.x

Again: check on GitHub under "Issues" which open Issues there are for a release, and/or google "Rails 3.y.z Problems" with the exact version number,  so you get a feel of what problems could be introduced by upgrading to a new / the latest version.

On Wikipedia they have a list of historic release dates for the major Rails versions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails

Comment: Do you know of anywhere that lists the EOL dates for each version of Rails, including the current? I'm looking for something like the list for Ruby versions at https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/ReleaseEngineering

Answer (score 3):

The Rails version numbers have been explained reasonably well (Joseph Le Brech's answer), but the Ruby version numbers are slightly confusing and I could see why it's not really obvious what's going on there.

Joseph's explanation of Rails version number scheme is correct for Rails, but Ruby has a slightly different approach

*1.9.3* is the most recent version of Ruby. Having said that, it was only released maybe a month ago, so it's possible there are breaking issues with certain gems. (Yes, there were breakages. Ruby in general will introduce breaking things between `hotfix` releases, and it's true here too)

*1.9.2* is a more tried and true version of Ruby, having been out for at least 6 months now.

*1.8.7* is the last version in the Ruby 1.8 line. Major language rework happened between 1.8 and 1.9, so some older gems may not have made the transition.

*My recommendation*: use Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.3, unless you have really good excuses not to.

Ruby 1.9.2 is probably the safest bet for a Rails newbie, or green-field projects (projects without a lot of preexisting code). Rails 3.1 is an *excellent* version of Rails, which solves a lot of problems I had with the framework.

Rails 3.1 was released this fall, so old tutorials won't work, or will give odd errors. Try to look and read what version of Rails the book/tutorial/website/blog entry is talking about, before you dive in.

Comment: a gem may have used a workaround to overcome a quirk in 1.9.2 this is why upgrading to 1.9.3 might produce glitches if the quirks are ironed out. it's probably not worth upgrading the whole chain, for example upgrading to a newer linux distro just for the heck of it will produce similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Latest stable release is always shown on the Ruby on Rails website's home page here http://rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 2):

To list all rails versions by `gem`:

```
gem list -ra rails | grep -G "^rails\ "
```

It's also helpful for cheeking what is the latest version for 4.x, 3.x and 2.x too.

Answer (score 1):

According to [rubygems](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails), it's `3.1.3`. Looks like you forgot a `.`.

Answer (score 1):

`major.minor.hotfix` hotfixes will never change the behavior of an app unless you previously had a workaround for a bug implemented. Apps can easily be upgraded thru minor revisions, but it's usually not worth it and can be a distraction from getting features out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

The latest release is 3.1.3. This is a minor release which has security and minor improvements.

The main version is 3.1, while minor upgrades are included in 3.1.x releases.

Anyway you should always use the latest one.

Comment: what about the ruby version, 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 ?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3 is in stable version

Comment: question: will specifying a gem install without a version get the latest stable version? or is that not a safe assumption...

Comment: I disagree -- it is dangerous advice to say "always use the latest one".  It really depends on how much change you want to introduce into your existing Rails app, and how well-tested the "latest stable" is in the field. e.g. check the open bugs against the version in question.

Comment: Sure you are right, but I suppose that if I'm starting a new app (with the latest rails) I should use latest gems.

Answer (score 0):

usually if you'll pull the latest rails gem, it's the stable one (unless once in history). although you can still use ruby 1.8.x version with the latest rails 3.x, it is more recommended to use 1.9.x.

anyway, everything you might need is in http://guides.rubyonrails.org and some nice people (including myself) are answering all bunch of questions in IRC on irc.freenode.net (#rubyonrails and #railsbridge)

good luck

Answer (score 0):

The latest release is 6.0. it was released on August 16, 2019, making Webpack default, adding mailbox routing. Rails 5.2 is still maintained.

Comment: This question was asked almost 9 years ago--other answers (including accepted) have already provided relevant details (at the time) as well as how to locate the latest version at this time. When answering a question with other answers, ensure you're adding new and useful information. Also be aware of when the original question was posted.